# Physic problem: calculating distance just from speed

Tags: flash, flex4, physics, game-physics

I'm creating a drag based control in Flex / Flash, similar to a film strip, where an individual can swipe horizontally to scroll through the items.  To make the control feel a bit more natural I've added some inertia to slow the scrolling once a swipe has taken place.  When first loaded up there will be five items in view with 'x' numbers of items to scroll through with the 3rd item centred and selected.

My problem though is that I want, when animating, a swipe gesture to determine whether an item will end up the middle (3rd position) and adjust its movement calculation accordingly so it docks with the 3rd / centre position.  Imagine you perform a long swipe, it flys pasts 'x' amount of items, but as it slows to a stop it elegantly stops with an item centred / in the 3rd position.  To do this I believe I need to determine the distance to travel just from the speed value (as time is irrelevent to the user experience, i.e. a longer / stronger swipe would justify a longer animation skimming through the items).

At the moment I'm invoking the animation routine (with inertia) in the ENTER_FRAME event when the user generates a MOUSE_UP event.  When they do this, I obtain the speed of drag (by monitoring this beforehand) and then decrement this speed value on each call of the ENTER_FRAME event until it reaches an appropriate value to stop the animation.

Unfortunately all the speed calculations I've seen deal with Speed and Time to determine distance, I just need Speed.  Admittedly, my knowledge isn't strong in this area so I might be missing the obvious.

Cheers in advance...

Comment: Semi-obvious: If you're animating, time is already a factor.  Animation implies a change over time.

Comment: Just out of interest, what do you think the difference is between speed and velocity? I can't see the vector aspect of velocity coming into play here.

Comment: @ cHao - The animation is invoked and a speed is retreived.  The time of the animation is unknown (or possibly calculable) as the speed is reduced on each cycle of the animation.

@ paxdiablo - Apologies, I was mixing my words here.  I have the speed and value I decrement the speed by.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification directed @cHao. I was confused to, but that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

First determine the position you end up at if you used the default deceleration value, then figure out which item is nearest the center when you scroll to that position, and then calculate a new deceleration value that ends up exactly on that item.

I don't remember off the top of my head the math to make such calculations, but it's calculus, probably taking an integral or something like that.

This way you could calculate the time if you wanted but you don't need to know that in advance.

(btw I think you'd need to do a special case where the swipe isn't fast enough to move over even one item. It's possible that the user just jiggles the mouse slightly and in that case you should have the current item recenter.)

---

Personally I wouldn't take the approach you are going with however. I would simply allow it to scroll with the default deceleration value, and then slowly center whichever item ends up nearest when the speed gets below a certain threshold. That would mean the item could overshoot and then slowly scroll back, but I think a slight overshoot and then correction would look cool.

Comment: I guess that's the problem when performing these calculations, the acceleration is not a constant as it decremented on each iteration.

Comment: Why is the acceleration changing? Just change the speed but don't change the acceleration.

Comment: Also I don't think the quiver / wobble effect will be desirable in this particular instance, hence the requirement to calculate the distance to allow a graceful docking.

Answer (score 0):

If you decrement speed by a fixed amount (call it D) each time you enter a new frame, and stop when speed drops below a certain threshold, then the problem's pretty easy. Set the threshold to, say, 0.7*D, then you can divide initial speed by D and round down, that gives you the number of frames you'll traverse, call it N. Then reduce initial speed to, say, (N+0.01)*D, and you're done.

Comment: Not sure I follow you here.  My decrement amount is fixed (0.95) and the threshold to halt is when the speed reach 0.05 or below with the initial speed of 24pixels per frame.  How does this figure into calculating the distance?

Comment: @SeanCocteau: 24 pixels per frame? I think I misinterpreted "frame" because you said your control was "similar to a film strip". In your example, the agent will move through (24-0.05)/0.95 = 25 frames (and then reach an unhealthy state where its speed is 0.25, too fast to stop but too slow to enter the next frame). How wide is an item, in pixels?